# App like Kahoot; Laravel Sanctum or Passport?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, laravel-passport, laravel-sanctum

I want to build a game-app like kahoot, for fun! :)
This will be an app where guests can either register and create a game or just get invited and enter the created game with a PIN. Then they can answer all kinds of questions.

It will be a SPA structured application. Laravel based with Vue on the frontend.I was already thinking of using an ecosystem like Laravel Echo or maybe something like Pusher for websockets.

However, I am puzzled when thinking about what authentication method to use. What authentication would be better in this case? Either Laravel Sanctum or Passport? What would be the benefits and disadvantages of these methods to use? What would you recommend? They both look pretty good options to me. However, I don't want to get stuck at a certain point because I have chosen the wrong kind of auth-method.

I'd love to hear your thoughts about the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Laravel 7 or higher, I recommend installing Sanctum, it's light weight and is super flexible with VueJS.

But, if it's a big project, use the Passport, it has more features.

See this video from Andre Madarang maybe it helps you out.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9oIu6jiYLk

But, if you know spanish see this from Aprendible:

- Part I - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAdp3lpdNfo
- Part II -
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lzm_7ymlgAU
- Part III - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mrhs68JOFQ

Comment: Thank you very much! Will check the video for sure :)